# jupyter notebook execute shell script and ignore the output logs

Tags: python, shell, logging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I execute a shell script in jupyter and ignore its logged outputs to standardout and standarderr?

```
!sh my_shell_file.sh > /dev/null
```

Does not work and is still logging plenty of logs.

### background

I want to silence the logs of spark: [How to stop INFO messages displaying on spark console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-info-messages-displaying-on-spark-console)

and not even:

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("FATAL")
```

or

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

worked when supplying a:

```
spark-shell -i my_scala.scala
```

with contents of

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("FATAL")

// do some stuff
// generating plenty of logs
```

### edit

Manually setting:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.FATAL)

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

fails as well to silence the logs.

```
20/11/05 15:18:16 WARN net.ScriptBasedMapping: Exception running /etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py 10.15.250.71 
ExitCodeException exitCode=1:   File "/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py", line 63
    print rack
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(rack)?

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:1008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1213)
```

is still logged thousandas of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple: `&>/dev/null` [How do I suppress output from this Shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797139/how-do-i-suppress-output-from-this-shell-command) will solve it and also ignore the standarderror output of spark.